# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column "content://media/internal/audio/media"

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch all rintone, audio,and all .mp3 files from internal and external storage, it works well till api 29 but in android 10 device i get  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column "content://media/internal/audio/media" error, and my app crash
so please tell me how to resolve it
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: from https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Ringdroid i have used this code for making MP3 cutter app